# Chained Assignment vs. Single assignment

Tags: javascript, optimization, variable-declaration

I have a snippet of very basic code snippet, and was trying to optimize it.

Below is the js code(not optimized):

```
var new_pod = ""; 
var resume_pod = "";
var claim_track_pod = "";
var return_track_pod = "";
```

Optimized JS code:

```
var new_pod = resume_pod = claim_track_pod = return_track_pod = "";
```

**Question 1:** *How does the two implementation differs?*

**Question 2:** *Is the second optimized way accepted by all browsers?*

**Question 3:** *Is the second optimized way the correct way to do it?*

Comment: It's style matter only. I prefer first one as it's more readable and less error prone.

Comment: The second one declares one local and three global variables, and would throw an error in `strict mode`. Use the first one.

Comment: You are not going to optimize a program by caring about how you initialized a handful of empty variables, that's the completely wrong way to spend your time - JS JIT's are going to optimize it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The statements are not equivalent.

You should focus on writing a good code first and let the JS compressors do the job of code compression and optimization second. Almost never it is justified to do that by hand. The same way you would call someone unrolling the loops in C by hand, crazy.

The optimizations are always browser / JS engine dependent, therefore it is hard to say for sure what the performance implications are if you go your way.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to keep it short, it should be like that:

```
var new_pod, resume_pod, claim_track_pod, return_track_pod;
new_pod = resume_pod = claim_track_pod = return_track_pod = "";
```

or alternatively

```
var new_pod="", resume_pod="", claim_track_pod="", return_track_pod="";
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one declares one local and three global variables:

```
var new_pod = resume_pod = claim_track_pod = return_track_pod = "";
```

> new_pod: local
>
> resume_pod: global
>
> claim_track_pod: global
>
> return_track_pod: global

As `return_track_pod` is assigned to first, this statement would throw an error in `strict mode` along the lines of:

```
ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable return_track_pod
```

Only use the first one, as the second one might bring unexpected behaviors.